# Strange error in project with Webpack and ES6

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am not an expert in webpack, please help me understand what the
error is. I need to attach an event handler this way, and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. This colleague wrote this webpack config, I am still not familiar with the webpack.

```js
    class Store {
        constructor(storeParams) {
            this.products = storeParams.products;

            this.container = document.querySelector('.js-goods');
        }

        renderProducts() {
            const productTemplate = document.querySelector('.js-goods-temp');

            for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
                const item = productTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
                const id = this.products[i].id;
                const titleElem = item.querySelector('.js-title');
                const descrElem = item.querySelector('.js-info');
                const imageElem = item.querySelector('.js-img');
                const priceElem = item.querySelector('.js-price');
                const btnAddElem = item.querySelector('.js-add');

                titleElem.innerHTML = this.products[i].title;
                descrElem.innerHTML = this.products[i].descr;
                imageElem.src = this.products[i].image;
                priceElem.innerHTML = this.products[i].price;
                btnAddElem.setAttribute('data-id', id);
                this.container.appendChild(item);

                btnAddElem.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    console.log(this.products[i].id) // When I try to hang an event handler this way, an error is output to the console - see below
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

> goods-item.js:1 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
>   TypeError: G:\firststep\store\src\components\goods-item\goods-item.js: path.inShadow is not a function
>   at ReplaceSupers.Function (G:\firststep\store\node_modules\babel-helper-replace-supers\lib\index.js:50:15)
>   at NodePath._call (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:53:20)
>   at NodePath.call (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:40:17)
>   at NodePath.visit (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:88:12)
>   at TraversalContext.visitQueue (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:112:16)
>   at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:79:17)
>   at TraversalContext.visit (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:138:19)
>   at Function.traverse.node (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\index.js:80:17)
>   at NodePath.visit (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:95:18)
>   at TraversalContext.visitQueue (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:112:16)
>   at TraversalContext.visitSingle (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:84:19)
>   at TraversalContext.visit (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:140:19)
>   at Function.traverse.node (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\index.js:80:17)
>   at NodePath.visit (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:95:18)
>   at TraversalContext.visitQueue (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:112:16)
>   at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (G:\firststep\store\node_modules@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:79:17)
>   at eval (webpack:///./src/components/goods-item/goods-item.js?:1:7)
>   at Object../src/components/goods-item/goods-item.js (http://localhost:9000/js/app.min.js:96:1)
>   at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:9000/js/app.min.js:20:30)
>   at eval (webpack:///./src/static/js/index.js?:3:18)
>   at Object../src/static/js/index.js (http://localhost:9000/js/app.min.js:108:1)
>   at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:9000/js/app.min.js:20:30)
>   at http://localhost:9000/js/app.min.js:84:18
>   at http://localhost:9000/js/app.min.js:87:10

Comment: What is your Babel config? It sounds like you're using a Babel 6 plugin on Babel 7, which doesn't generally work for Babel's first-party plugins.

Comment: share your webpack.config.js/webpack.config, so we can help you.

Comment: @loganfsmyth your advice helped me

Comment: @VictorCastro thanks for the response my friend, I solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem - set another preset `@babel/preset-env` instead `babel-preset-env`,

thanks to the advice of @loganfsmyth